# BCP export in UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, bcp

I'm trying to export data from SQL Server using BCP utility on cmd into a .txt file.

My requirement is that the exported .txt file needs to be in UTF-8 encoding, but whatever I do it always comes out as 1252 ANSI.

I'm running SQL Server 2017, BCP utility version is 14. My code is as follows:

```
bcp "Select top 1000 * from MyTable" queryout "C:\ETL\Accuracy_A3.txt" -c -C 65001 -T -S "MYMSSQLSERVER" -d "MyWorkDB"
```

The code works and doesn't give me any errors, but the resulting file is still in 1252. I've tried to convert it to other code pages, but it's till in 1252, so I believe that I'm calling the switch wrong or something. I've also tried to pull out a whole table instead of `queryout` and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The `-c -C 65001` [is correct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq). For English data, UTF-8 looks just like 1252. How did you determine it's 1252?

Comment: How do you know that the export failed? What does `always comes out as 1252 ANSI.` mean? 1252 isn't ANSI (or rather US-ASCII), it's essentially Latin 1. UTF8 *is identical to ANSI* for character values 0-127. Latin 1 bytes are the same in that range too.

Comment: This page is UTF8. If you save *this* page as UTF8, 1252 or any other single-byte codepage you'll see that the English characters and digits remain the same. All (well most) codepages use the same values in the 0-127 range

Comment: I determined that it's in 1252 when I open the file in in EmEditor and it it tells you the current encoding. I use notepad to save it as UTF-8 and then it registers that it's UFT-8 in EmEditor.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The export doesn't fail and produces a text file with all the correct data in it. The issue is that the encoding or code page of the text file is always 1252 (Western Euro), whereas I need it to be UTF-8. I understand that the characters are very similar, however the program which picks up this text file can only read UTF-8 coding.

Comment: @ATcode again, how do you know it's not *UTF8 already*? ANSI and UTF8 are *identical*. As in, the same. It's only non-ANSI characters that differ between UTF8 and other encodings. Are you sure the problem isn't the program you use to read that file?

Comment: `I determined that it's in 1252 when I open the file in in EmEditor` that says nothing except perhaps that EmEditor whatever it is has a bug, or incorrect UTF8 detection. Does the file have *any* non-English characters? If not, EmEditor or *anyone, even humans* can't tell whether it's UTF8 or not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if it is already in UTF-8, how can I make other programs detect that it's UTF-8 as notepad, Firefox, notepad++, EmEditor as well as SQL and ACL import pick it up as 1252 and not UTF-8. If I save it as UTF-8 in notepad, then magically everything works.

Comment: You still haven't show what the file contains. You're asking people to guess what you're doing, what the problem is. It's impossible to help this way

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It doesn't have any non-English characters so I am easily able to convert between the two manually, however I'm trying to automate a part of the process.

Comment: There's nothing to automate. Unless you post an *actual* example that demonstrates the problem there's no point in this question. There may be an invisible character you don't know about.

Comment: Please see below:   [What happens when I open the file]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYicz.png
  [What the file opened looks like]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQBjj.png
  [What I need to be]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19J2L.png
  [Encoding on Notepad++]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK6B9.png

Comment: @ATcoder I suggest you have a look at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/. I also suggest that, having opened the file in Notepad++ (your last screenshot), you change the encoding in that menu to UTF-8, save the file under another name, and then do binary comparison between the two files (`fc /b file1.txt file2.txt`).

Comment: @GSerg,the bin compare just shows me that the the UTF8 file is longer.

Comment: That means either you added the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (which you should have not done), or you do in fact have funny characters in the file and it was indeed not UTF-8. Please investigate that.

Comment: bcp.exe doesn't add a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark, aka Preamble) when writing file content. You can verify this with a hex editor, such as wxHexEditor or Visual Studio Code with the hexdump extension. Your screen shots aren't showing a character encoding problem, though, they appear to be showing a line break character problem. Again, with a hex editor, you should be able to see that the line breaks are linefeed only (0x0A) instead of carriage return linefeed (0x0D 0x0A). You probably need to fix your bcp record delimiter so that it's outputting `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone, by adding a -r "\r\n" it appears to solve the problem. Thanks a great deal.

Comment: It's inaccurate that "ANSI" encoding (Windows code page 1252) is the same as "UTF-8" encoding (code page 65001).  Each of them contains "ASCII" single byte encodings of characters between 32 (space) and 126 (tilde) but then they differ.  British currency symbol £ ("pounds") is an example of a difference.  Data may be not recognised as UTF-8 when BOM is not included, but some people feel strongly against including it.  It is possible to save a UTF-8 BOM on its own and to append your data after this BOM.  A text editor will recognise this as UTF-8, but a data import process may be confused.